# firebase.auth.Auth.signInWithCredential is deprecated. Please use firebase.auth.Auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential instead

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, ionic4

When is use this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential everything works great in my Ionic app.  I can sign in using Google authentication and the user profile is pushed to firebase.  However, I get an error in the console that signInWithCredential is deprecated and to use signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential.  The problem is that signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential doesn't provide any user data(uid, user email, displayname)...it's all null.

So what can I do?  The console error is saying not to use signInWithCredential even though it's working.  signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential returns null for the user.

```js
  async googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    try {

      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      });
      return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
      ).then((credential) => {
        console.log('creds', credential);
        this.updateUserData(credential);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
      private updateUserData(user) {
    const userRef: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference = firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
    };
    console.log('user data', data);
    return userRef.set(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE 11 Dec. 2019**

Note that the [`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inand-retrieve-data-with-credential) method has been deprecated and that we need to use the [`signInWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcredential) method.

So, the code shall be adapted to

```
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
  ).then((credential) => {
    console.log('creds', credential.user);
    this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  });
```

---

If I correctly understand your question, I think your problem comes from the fact that the two methods return a different object:

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCredential), `signInWithCredential()` returns a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object,

*while*

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential), `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()` returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) object, which contains a `User` object.

So you should modify your code as follows

```
  ....
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
  ).then((credential) => {
    console.log('creds', credential.user);
    this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  });
```

Comment: signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

I just want to clarify that `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`, and not the `signInWithCredential`, has been deprecated in [version 6](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_600_-_may_7_2019) of the Firebase JS SDK.

Furthermore the function `signInWithCredential` has now been updated to return a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential), so you should be able to access the *uid*, *email*, etc. under the *user* object on the `UserCredential`

Answer (score 1):

signInWithCredential Worked for me (JavaScript - version 9) https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth?hl=en#signinwithcredential

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
...
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const credential = signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
.then((result) => {
  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
  const { user } = result;
  const idToken = credential.idToken;
  return { credential, idToken, user };
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle Errors here.
  // const errorCode = error.code
  // const errorMessage = error.message
  // The email of the user's account used.
  // const {email} = error.customData
  // The AuthCredential type that was used.
  // const credential =
  //    GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error)
  // ...
});
```